# Resize image file laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, resize

I installed the patch "intervention/image", "must-master" in order to make my image to reduce the size of it to 300 by 300.
I've done some forms and appears to me always the same mistake.

**Call to a member function resize() on string**

which got the error?

**Controller**

```
public function updateProfile() {

    $file = Input::file('imagem');
    $profileData = Input::except('_token');
    $validation = Validator::make($profileData, User::$profileData);
    if ($validation->passes()) {
        if ($file == null) {
            User::where('id', Input::get('id'))->update($profileData);
            Session::flash('message', 'Perfil editado com sucesso');
            return view('backend/perfil.index'); 
        }
        $file = array_get($profileData,'imagem');
        $destinationPath = 'imagens/perfil';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $reduzir = $filename -> resize (300,300); 
        $profileData['imagem'] = $filename;
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);


        User::where('id', Input::get('id'))->update($profileData);
        Session::flash('message', 'Perfil editado com sucesso');
        return Redirect::to('backend/perfil');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('backend/perfil')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be because of these reasons

Have you added this aliases in your `app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
         //add these three at the bottom
        'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 
        'HTML'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        'Image'     => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
],
```

I believe that you already have form and html helper.

And use this function in the Controller

i.e., just pass the image and size value as the Parameter to this function

In the controller you have just call the below function like

```
 $resizedImage  =   $this->resize($image, $request->get('image_size'));
```

And the `resize()` function was given below

```
private function resize($image, $size)
    {
        try 
        {
            $extension      =   $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imageRealPath  =   $image->getRealPath();
            $thumbName      =   'thumb_'. $image->getClientOriginalName();

            //$imageManager = new ImageManager(); // use this if you don't want facade style code
            //$img = $imageManager->make($imageRealPath);

            $img = Image::make($imageRealPath); // use this if you want facade style code
            $img->resize(intval($size), null, function($constraint) {
                 $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            return $img->save(public_path('images'). '/'. $thumbName);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: can you help me? I do not understand why this does not work.
It's not about that matter but with password.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716593/update-profile-password-laravel-5

Comment: Okay, i will checkout that, how about the issue in image ?

Comment: I call the class Image and appeared Image undfefined

Comment: Pls check your image path that you get as input !

Comment: the path is right 
appear this "Undefined variable: request"

Comment: 1. Is your form multipart enabled 2. you enabled request helper in your controller ?

Comment: Form multipart is enable.
I enable request helper in my controller? i don't understand the ask sory

Comment: Ahm i am in travel i will reply in 1.5 hr

Comment: Already discovered. This line was doing conflict   $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

insert is only    
Image::make($file)->resize(400, 400)->save($destinationPath.$filename);
Thanks again :)
good trip

Comment: That's really great. Thanks for wishes ;) Good time ahead !