# update profile password laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, password-encryption

I am working in laravel 5.1 and my update profile was working but will not encrypted and not working now.
When I try to update the user table will also password_confirmation field and causes a conflict in the database. I do not understand.
In the form says successfully but the database does not update any

**Code**

```
public function updatePassword() {
    $passwordData = Input::except('_token');
    $validation = Validator::make($passwordData, User::$passwordData);
    if ($validation->passes()) {
        array_forget($passwordData,'password_confirmation');
        User::where(array(
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
            ));
        Session::flash('password', 'Perfil editado com sucesso');
        return Redirect::to('backend/perfil/password');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('backend/perfil/password')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    }   
}
```

**user**

```
public static $passwordData = array(
        'password'              => 'required|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required'
        );
```

Comment: You got any error or password mismatch ?

Comment: No..Always say "success" and my password not updatetd

Comment: {"id":"2","password":"ola"} but does not update the database :c

Comment: if i take the line "        array_forget($passwordData,'password_confirmation');
" appear this error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password_confirmation' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `id` = 2, `password` = hi, `password_confirmation` = hi, `updated_at` = 2015-11-15 05:18:07 where `password` = y$R/xbedKn3XVwIkhFoxqkIe5G1QP/iR2lSCMCUhxukNa5zA.f9aKgS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this simple steps to get rid of anything

**Step 1 :** Get the password from the form

`$PasswordData = Input::all();`

**Step 2 :** Validate your password

```
Validator::extend('pwdvalidation', function($field, $value, $parameters) {
            return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password);
        });
```

**Step 3 :** Define the validation rule in your `User` Model

```
public static $rulespwd = array('OldPassword' => 'required|pwdvalidation',
        'NewPassword' => 'required|confirmed|alphaNum|min:5|max:10',
        'NewPassword_confirmation' => 'required',
        );
```

`Note :` You shall define your own rule according to your need

**Step 4 :** If the rule is passed, then update else throw error messages to your view

```
$validator = Validator::make($PasswordData, User::$rulespwd, $messages);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->password = Input::get('NewPassword');
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to(Session::get('urlpath') . '/changepassword')->withInput()->with('Messages', 'The Password Information was Updated');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to(Session::get('urlpath') . '/changepassword')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
```

Comment: humm i need create one field for oldpassword?

Comment: finaly went to db now need to encrypt it

Comment: Is already :)
Again always present, thanks:)
You will save my project for college xD

Comment: Welcome, you are now ok ??

Comment: Yes, is missing the resize and destroy image when the update profile picture :) tomorrow I hope to get it

Comment: Yeah, All the best ;) (y)